# How to modify third party code imported with git (subtree, submodules, etc)?

Tags: ios, git, git-submodules, git-subtree

I have a project that needs to support iOS7. I want to use a lib (let's call it LIB) that does not support iOS7 but could be easily modified to do so. I also expect LIB will change quite often.

What will be an ideal solution:

1. I include LIB's code into my project (tag with the last
   release)
2. I modify LIB to support iOS7 (usually only one commit). I **do not** want to push this commit to LIB's original repository but want to save it in my projects repository.
3. When new LIB's version is released I update it in my project and
   merge with changes from point 2 or just redo these changes.
4. I do not want to have LIB's full history in my project history (as git subtree do AFAIK). Only something like "LIB changed to 1.2.42;  LIB updated to support iOS7;"

I can copy LIB's code myself or maintain LIB's fork with iOS7 support but it is time consuming and not very "automagically". I have checked git submodules and git subtree but as far as I understand it is impossible to have point 2, is it?.

What is a best approach to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can … maintain LIB's fork with iOS7 support

That's the best option here, I think.

Fork the library and use your fork in your application. When you want to use a new version of the upstream library, merge those changes into your fork and update your main application to use the new version of your forked library.

This is certainly possible to do using Git submodules, though a dependency manager like [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/) might be a better option. I generally prefer to use dependency managers when I can, though I'm not an iOS developer and can't say much about CocoaPods in particular.

Comment: Thank you. CocoaPods unfortunately will not work because the lib I need is written in Swift and CocoaPods supports Swift pods only for iOS8+ projects. But git submodules should work.

Comment: Do you know for sure is it possible or not to achieve point 2 only using Git?

Comment: @Avt, if you fork the library there is no (technical) need to contribute your changes back to the upstream version of the library. If those changes would be helpful to other developers it would be nice of you to share them, and depending on how the library is licensed you might be required to. But the license implications will be the same regardless of whether you use Git submodules or some other mechanism.

Comment: Thank you. I understand how it could be done with a fork. I just do not think my fork will be really useful and popular. My question is should I continue to search for solution that uses only Git possibilities (like git submodules with some specific and rarely used options). Or fork and a copy of the LIB's code are the only two ways to receive what I need.

Comment: Don't fork things because you think they'll be popular. Fork them because you need to fork them. If it's useful to _you_ then it's useful enough. I _think_ you're looking for a way to store changes that you make to the library in your main repository. I urge you not do that. They are two separate code bases, and should be treated as such. Either contribute iOS7 support to the library directly, or maintain a fork with those changes for your own personal use.